# Germany Visa application, Not refused Not Accepted either

Tags: germany

I'm doing a Master degree in a University in Turkey. I secured the Erasmus+ internship grant for Germany. The grant provides monthly support of 600Euros and for my Visa application provided personal funds to complete the monthly budget up to 725euros per month.

I applied for a 12-month national Visa, and İ provided all the required documents proving my student status as well. All the requirements were met. However the consulate officer received all my documents, returned my passport to me and asked me to go and wait. I was neither accepted or given a rejection.

He mentioned that I'll need a monthly upkeep of 1600Euros, and I was surprised because the information on the website stipulated that students require an upkeep of 720Euros.

Questions:

1. Has anyone ever experienced such situation?
2. What could be the possible outcome?
3. What steps can I take regarding this?

Comment: This question might be better suited on the academic site.

Comment: Cost of living vary a lot between different cities and regions in Germany. Although €1600 per month sounds like a lot, there are at least many places in Germany where it in reality is not possible to live if you only can afford €725 in monthly expenses.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll ask the question on the academic site too.